# List objects in a panel

Tags: c#, winforms, list

i got a question regarding C#

I'm about making a program to hold all my daily tasks, and i need to show them in some kind of panel/list, Ive tryed with the gridview and it worked fine, but i don't want a "table" look, i rather want somekind of access database look, so it creates a new textbox/label maybe a panel with several informations - got any suggestions for this one? if it's possible in a easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just use `WindowsForms`, you can, for example, define a `UserTaskControl:UserControl` that holds unique set of controls you need for single entry.

Let's say you need for single entry to have *Title*, *StartDate*, *EndDate*, *Description*, so you can create a control with 4 `TextBoxes` or 2 TextBoxes and 2 `Calendar` controls (matter of design choice).

After define on main window TableLayoutPanel and at runtime add new instances of your `UserTaskControl` in the moment you need a new entry in your task list.

If you want to make things much better, consider of using `WPF`, as there you can use also `UI Virtualization` technique (just one example), which *can* make a difference  in regard of `WindowsForms`, if you have *too much* entries in your list (*too much* is application specific measure, obviously). But in this case you need to learn WPF and learn to use it in a good way, which is a right thing to do IMHO, but depends on how much time you have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That should be it!

so my tablelayout panel contains the usertaskcontol:usercontrol! ah! smart!

Comment: @Mathias: be careful, keep an eye on memory usage. If your list becomes too long, you can decide to not show all tasks in one time, but separate them in some logical groups (by date, for example, state, priority, whatever)

Comment: WPF is very nice for making custom controls, this is true. Can build them quickly right there in xaml.

Comment: Tigran - as far as i understood i can in the TableLayoutPanel define how many usercontrols to show right?

Comment: @Mathias: Sure, you add controls like a children, so you can decide when to add a new one, when do not do that.

Comment: Sweet! 

so i programmicly create the usercontrol?

Comment: :) Sure, like you create your form on any other UI object.

Comment: i create my forms by drag&drop.. but i guess that isen't possible with the usercontrol :D

Comment: @Mathias:  you need to create it NOT from designer, but from code. Google on web for examples, how to create a user control from C# and add it like a child to another (TableLayout in your case). It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

A listview with checkboxes to check off when you've completed them? You can make the items editable or put in an "editing panel" to use to edit the values.

So you'd have:

- [x] Get dressed
- [x] Take out the garbage
- [x] Make breakfast
- [x] Ask ? on stackoverflow !
- [ ] Implement solution

[image]

I did this one for work as a task tracker.

Comment: not exactly.. 
lets say I've got a task with a heading, some text and a priority,
then i want to by code create a label, and a textbox wich would look like this:

Heading: Take out the trash
Text: its very important!
priority: 3

and i would like to create that for each obejct in my arraylist/generic list

Comment: I'm still a little confused, I guess. Are you wanting to display them all on screen at once, then?